# In dl4j word2 vec vecs.similarity method throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, deeplearning4j, dl4j

```
    File gModel = new File("D:/FluidAI/WordVec/pathToSaveModel.txt");
    Word2Vec vecs = WordVectorSerializer.readWord2VecModel(gModel);//("D:/FluidAI/WordVec/pathToSaveModel.txt");
    vecs.setTokenizerFactory(t);
    vecs.setSentenceIter(iter);
    //vecs.set
    vecs.fit();

    WordVectorSerializer.writeWordVectors(vecs, "pathToWriteto.txt"); 
     WordVectorSerializer.writeWord2VecModel(vecs, "pathToSaveModel.txt");
     Collection<String> st=vecs.wordsNearest("enclave", 10);
     System.out.println(st);


    double cosSim = vecs.similarity("extn", "dausa");
    System.out.println(cosSim);
```

**in the vecs.similarity throws null pointer exception after traning**

Comment: Do you have a full stack trace? Are you using 0.8.0?

Comment: Hi nullpointer at vecsimplarity

Comment: Yes..I know. I need a full stack trace showing what the actual problem is. If english isn't your first language, might I recommend one of our foreign language support channels like mandarin?  https://gitter.im/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-cn